# Prayer on Kala(time) and Savitar(speed)?

Tags: gods, mantras, time, stotra, prayer

Who is God of Time, and any Mantra or Prayer, stotra anything related to Time aspect.. or for **God of Time or Kala** and **Savitar (god of speed)**

**Kala Bhairava** is manifestation of **Shiva** in the form of **Time**.. is there any prayer, stotra related to that God, **prayer in which he is described as controller of ones Time**.. Is Kali God of Time too..?

Anything(mantra,stotra,prayer) related to Time and Speed aspect of God and Savitar, is Helpful,,

While Searching I Found these related to Time.. Hymn on Time [One](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av19053.htm) [Two](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av19054.htm)

Comment: I work hard and I always feel like Im short on time or that Im working slowly, if I had just few more time or If I was working fast, I would have completed the task. So Im thinking about Kala and Savitar

Comment: are there any vedic technique to be fast at whatever you are doing or to get more time

Comment: How do you know Savitar is god of speed? Where did you get that information from?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma From Wikipedia [Savitar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitr) and Sacred_texts [Savitar](https://www.google.com/search?domains=www.sacred-texts.com&q=Savitar+speed&sitesearch=www.sacred-texts.com)

Comment: @HinduKid: What you had quoted in the question part regarding [TIME](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av19053.htm), is from Atharva Veda, but not from Rig Veda.  Only Indra was eulogised as having knowledge of existence of Manu, from whom Humans emanated,  and others (RV 4.26.1).  If knowledge of many people from yore, is called TIME, then Indra is the Kala.

Comment: @ any mantra, stotra of Kala Bhairava as manifestation of Shiva in the form of Time.

Comment: Are you looking for the kakabhairava ashtakam? If so, it is [here](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/shiva/kalabhairava_ashtakam.php)

Comment: anything extra.. I have huge load of work to-do, and very little time , a month to complete, what should I be praying to God, which Mantra/Stotra, and to which GOD..?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv ^^

Comment: @HinduKid: I don't know how to respond.  As I had already mentioned, there is a vast difference between Vedic gods and Puranic gods.  if you are looking for the kakabhairava ashtakam, then read that [stotram](https://greenmesg.org/stotras/shiva/kalabhairava_ashtakam.php).  Otherwise stick to  **aim** (ऐं) bIja mantra, which applies both to Saraswati (Shakti) and Vedic God Indra

Answer (score 3):

Rig Veda [II.38](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02038.htm) is dedicated to Savitar, who was praised in Gayatri mantra.

> 1  UPRISEN is Savitar, this God, to quicken, Priest who neglects not this most constant duty. To the Gods, verily, he gives rich treasure,
>   and blesses him who calls them to the banquet.
>
> 2  Having gone up on high, the God broad-handed spreads his arms
>   widely forth that all may mark him. Even the waters bend them to his
>   service: even this wind rests in the circling region.
>
> 3 Though borne by swift steeds he will yet unyoke them: e’en the fleet
>   chariot hath he stayed from going. He hath checked e’en their haste
>   who glide like serpents. Night closely followed Savitar's dominion.
>
> 4 What was spread out she weaves afresh, re-weaving: the skilful
>   leaves his labour half-completed. He hath arisen from rest, **and parted
>   seasons:** Savitar hath approached, God, holy-minded.
>
> 5 Through various dwellings, through entire existence, spreads,
>   manifest, the household light of Agni. The Mother gives her Son the
>   goodliest portion, and Savitar hath sped to meet his summons.
>
> 6 He comes again, unfolded, fain for conquest: at home was he, the
>   love of all things moving. Each man hath come leaving his evil doings,
>   after the Godlike Savitar's commandment.
>
> 7 The wild beasts spread through desert places seeking their watery
>   share which thou hast set in waters. The woods are given to the birds.
>   These statutes of the God Savitar none disobeyeth.
>
> 8 With utmost speed, in restless haste at sunset Varuṇa seeks his
>   watery habitation. Then seeks each bird his nest, each beast his
>   lodging. In due place Savitar hath set each creature.
>
> 9 Him whose high law not Varuṇa nor Indra, not Mitra, Aryaman, nor
>   Rudra breaketh, Nor evil-hearted fiends, here for my welfare him I
>   invoke, God Savitar, with worship.
>
> 10 May they who strengthen bliss, and thought and wisdom, and the
>   Dames’ Lord and Narāśaṁsa aid us. That good may come to us and wealth
>   be gathered, may we be Savitar the God's beloved.
>
> 11 So come to us our hearts' desire, the bounty bestowed by thee, from
>   heaven and earth and waters, That it be well with friends and those
>   who praise thee, and, Savitar, with the loud-lauding singer.

### Sanskrit version is available [here](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rvsan/rv02038.htm).

- If we observe the 4th mantra, wherein it was mentioned that **and parted seasons**, we can understand tht Savitar was eulogised as TIME or kAla.
- If we closely observe, [Rig Veda II.1](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv02001.htm), wherein Agni was equalled to Savitar and Vayu also.  **Thus, Savitar is BRAHMAN**.
- vAyu was separately eulogised in [Rig Veda IV.48.](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv04048.htm)

Comment: Any Prayer or Mantra.

Comment: Prayer on God of Time, kala, kali ?

Comment: @HinduKid: As AGNI is Indra/Vayu/Varuna/brihaspati, etc, any mantra can refer to the TIME - Kala