# About Vedic calender/Hindu calender?

Tags: calendar, panchang

[image]

Please briefly explain Vedic Calender and do include these in your answer.

How did Ancient Hindus keep track of their days, time?

Did they follow like 7 days is a week/ 4 week a month/ 12 month a year?

Where can I get a Vedic calender version instead of Sunday, Monday or January, February. I want to track my days the Vedic way. In form of pdf or any website.

Comment: There was no week concept in earlier era.  Thithi, Nakshatra, Muhurtha played a vital role @HinduKid

Comment: Calendar was of 360 days with 12 months of 30days based on lunar cycle i.e. rotation of moon across 27 constellations split across 12 houses of Vedic horoscope https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_calendar . Dates were calculated based on points of full moon and no moon like festivals Ram Shukla navmi(9th) and Krishna Ashtmi(8th). Current 
western Roman calendar is some hotch botch of illogical 365 solar days with leap year every 4 years to impress Roman Emperors like Julius Caesar, Augustus etc.,All people in India today celebrate their birthdays on wrong date corresponding to Roman calendar.

Comment: Thats why dates of Diwali, Dusshera, Ram Navmi, Janamashtmi etc., fall on different dates on Roman western calendar every year, as its illogical in reality yet educated people in India mindlessly follow it after the British rule as they believe anything english is superior, kind of mental slavery. Celebrating week is later addition, came from Abrahamic religions as they celebrate weekly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sabbath on Sunday(Christians) or Saturday(Jews) or Friday(Muslims) respectively based on their Mosaic law which is form of Navgraha worship of 7 planets detailed in Vedic astrology

Comment: @ManuKumar Can you answer this questions [Kala](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/which-prayer-for-kalatime-and-savitarspeed) and [Time](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/37313/verses-and-mantras-in-veda-any-hindu-scripture-which-speak-about-time-space-a)

Answer (score 2):

Starting from creation.

First Bhagavan makes Pancha-Bhootas (5 elements) from Prakriti (akasha/ether).

Then he gives life to Brahma. Then Brahma starts creation.

Lifetime of Brahma = 100 'brahma-years'. (not human years, as you'll see shortly)

1 Brahma-year = 360 'brahma-days'.

1 Brahma-day = 1 daytime + 1 nighttime

1 Brahma-daytime = 1000 chatur-yuga (4-yuga or MahaYuga)

1 Chatur-Yuga = Krita + Treta + Dwapara + Kali Yugas

Kali Yuga = 100 + 1000 + 100 = 1200 'deva-years'

Dwapara Yuga = 200 + 2000 + 200 = 2400 'deva-years'

Treta Yuga = 300 + 3000 + 300 = 3600 'deva-years'

Satya/Krita Yuga = 400 + 4000 + 400 = 4800 'deva-years'

Total Chatur-Yuga = 12,000 'deva-years'

1 Deva-year = 360 'deva-days'

1 Deva-day = 1 daytime + 1 nighttime

1 Deva-daytime  = 6 'human-months' (Uttarayana mid-Jan to mid-July)
1 Deva-nighttime= 6 'human-months' (Dakshinayana mid-July to mid-Jan)

1 Deva-day = 1 'human-year'

1 Human-year (or just year) = 12 months

1 month = 2 fortnights (Krishna Paksha & Shukla Paksha)

1 fortnight = 2 weeks

1 week = 7 days

1 day = 60 nadis

1 nadi = 60 vinadis (or 24 minutes)

1 vinadi = 24 seconds

Thus 1 day = 60nadis x 24minutes. While 'modern' day is 24hours x 60minutes.

The years follow a 60-year cycle.

The seasons follow 6-season cycle - 2 months per season

The months follow a 12-month cycle

http://veda.wikidot.com/vedic-time-system