# Prayer for Kala(time) or God of Time?

Tags: mantras, time, prayer

Who is God of Time, and any Mantra or Prayer related to Time aspect.. or for God of Time

Comment: Duplicate of the [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/37508/3869), asked by yourself.  Whey are you posting similar question?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv No Im specifically searching for mantra or prayer on time..

Comment: If you are specific about answer for Time alone, your earlier question and and ask again.  Otherwise you can offer Bounty, which may draw attention of many members